# Can a method in vba call another method

Tags: excel, vba

I have written some code to connect to a database with excel. 
When retrieving information from the database you need two things when using ADODB.
- Connection to the database
- record to retrieve the information.

Now I have used the copy past to change what needs to be changed.
This creates a lot of duplicate data for setting the connection whats is always the same

can something be done like this.

```
Sub StartQ1

Call Openconnection

Call DoStuffWithRecord 

Call CloseConnection

End sub
```

or can something be done like this

```
Sub StartQ1

call Connection( call DoStuffWithRecord )

en sub
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you asking how to [pass arguments to procedures](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/calling-sub-and-function-procedures)?

Comment: Yes In a way, when you connect to database  you need to open the connection. then do stuff  and then close the connection. I don't know how to use this in arguments to do the stuff in between the opening en closing the connection, because the record is depended on the connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me transpose your question: When you make a phone call you establish a connection, then you talk, and when you finish talking you close the connection. Now, is it possible to establish the connection and talk in one operation? Perhaps the first counter question to come up is why I should want that.

I think what you mean is to return the connection to the `Main` procedure from a function call like

```
Set MyConnection = OpenConnection()
' then use the connection to make your call
MyData = GetData(MyConnection)
' pass the data to the manipulating procedure
DoStuffWithRecord MyData
' and then close the connection
CloseConnection MyConnection
```

The subject of your question is how to pass data and objects as parameters to procedures and function. There is a lot of literature on this available on the web. Prepare to invest an hour of your time. This link may not be the first one you will need but it's a good, [useful and reliable source of knowledge](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/byrefbyval.aspx).

Comment: I realize it was a stupid question, the trouble is how to ask a question the answer you have given provided me with solving the problem Thank you .